# Is there a way to check if a file is successfully uploaded with Google Drive API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am using the PHP sdk. I use the below code to insert files into drive.

```
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle($title);
$file->setDescription($description);
$file->setMimeType($mimeType);


if ($parentId != null) {
   $parent = new Google_ParentReference();
   $parent->setId($parentId);
   $file->setParents(array($parent));
}

$data = file_get_contents($uplodedFile['file']['tmp_name']);

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'mimeType' => $mimeType,
));
```

What I want to do is to know if the file is uploaded successfully to the server. This file may be very large so once it's completed, I want to have notification. Is there a way to do this with PHP sdk? I cannot use real time API.

Answer (score 2):

If you read their [API Documentation (insert)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), you can see they wrap their upload in a `try/catch` block.

```
try {
$data = file_get_contents($filename);

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
   'data' => $data,
   'mimeType' => $mimeType,
));

// Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
// print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

return $createdFile;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

And you'll notice in their `Response` section:

> If successful, this method returns a Files resource in the response body.

Meaning you'll get the uploaded file in return. Otherwise the `catch()` exception will be thrown as you see above.

Also, you'll notice if you scroll down, they have a PHP Library you could use, and in their function they state:

```
@return Google_DriveFile The file that was inserted. NULL is returned if an API error occurred.
```